# how to show tinymce on page?

Tags: laravel, tinymce

Hey do you get tinymce editor to show on a page?
I'm wanting to format my textarea when composing or editing blog posts.
But it's not displaying the little interface as expected - just the plain old textarea.
I've inserted the links and code (hopefully in the right place)
I'm using using laravel and bootstrap, also parsely for form validation.
Am I missing something?
Any tips would be great!
cheers.

here's my code:

```
{!! Html::style('css/parsley.css') !!}
{!! Html::style('css/select2.min.css') !!}
<script src="https://cloud.tinymce.com/stable/tinymce.min.js"></script>

<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#textarea',
        plugins: 'Link code table',
        menubar: 'table',
        toolbar: 'table'
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to add table plugin, like below.

```
<script>
    tinymce.init({
        selector: '#textarea',
        plugins: 'table',
        menubar: 'table',
        toolbar: 'table'
    });
</script>
```